# Relacionamento ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde estou com uma duvida em relação ao um relacionamento.

eu tenho 2 classes: Pessoa Interna e Unidade.

eu tenho as seguintes propriedades em  Pessoa Interna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PessoaInterna pertence a uma única unidade, porem em Unidade temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em unidade, uma pessoaInterna pode ser gestora de uma outra unidade.

Ou seja ao mesmo tempo que uma pessoaInterna pertence a uma unidade, ela também pode ser gestora de outra unidade.

Tentei fazer o seguinte relacionamento usando fluent api:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas esse erro acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que não posso usar 2 atributos de navegação com as mesmas classes. Qual seria a solução mais pratica?

Comment: olá Luan, evite imagens e coloque o texto é melhor para visualizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a sua linha de raciocínio, uma NcPessoaInterna poderá está relacionada em uma NcUnidade como pessoaInterna e a outra NcUnidade como gestor. Então isso quer disser que a class NcPessoaInterna pode ter mais do que 1 NcUnidade e NcUnidade pode ter mais do que 1 NcPessoaInterna, podendo ser o gestor ou não.

Então temos um relacionamento N-N entre as classes, sendo assim deve ser criada uma nova class que chamasse tabela-relaciona, ela fara o relacionamento entre a PessoaInterna e Unidade.

Em NcPessoaInterna altere a propriedade Unidade:

```
public List<NcPessoaInternaUnidade> Unidades { get; private set; }
```

Em NcUnidade troque as propridades PessoaInterna e Gestor por:

```
public List<NcPessoaInternaUnidade> PessoaInternas { get; private set; }
```

Crie a class de relacionameto:

```
public class NcPessoaInternaUnidade {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public NcPessoaInterna PessoaInterna { get; set; }
  public int PessoaInternaId { get; set; }
  public NcUnidade Unidade { get; set; }
  public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
  
  public bool Gestor { get; set; }
}
```

Utilize a propriedade booleana Gestor para declarar se NcPessoaInterna é um gestor (true) ou se ela é uma pessoa interna (false) em um NcUnidade.

Refaze API fluente dessa forma:

```
//Relacionamento NcPessoaInternaUnidade - NcPessoaInterna
modelBuilder.Entity<NcPessoaInternaUnidade>()
        .HasOne(p => p.PessoaInterna)
        .WithMany(b => b.Unidades)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaInternaId);

//Relacionamento NcPessoaInternaUnidade - NcUnidade
modelBuilder.Entity<NcPessoaInternaUnidade>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Unidade)
        .WithMany(b => b.PessoaInternas)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UnidadeId);
```

Espero ter ajudado.